# What is the correct way to receive and give attribution to CC BY-SA asset contributions on a project managed with git?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, contributor, cc-by-sa, assets

The Creative Commons website gives [this](https://creativecommons.org/use-remix/get-permission/) example for giving attribution to an image that was found on a website. For this project, contributors who wish to contribute assets would be sending the assets to me directly/through git and would likely not be hosted anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your README, include a statement for each asset used,

---

## Project

### Attribution

“Foo” by bar is licensed under CC BY 2.0

"Baz" by qux is licensed under CC BY 2.0

...

---

**Note:** bar and qux would be the names of the original creator of each asset specifically.

Or, you can create a separate file, e.g., `assets/NOTICE`; and include them there.